# Adding an onclick event in asp.net to an item inside the dropdpwn whose url is mentioned in sitemapnode

Tags: asp.net, onclick, web.sitemap, sitemapnode

I am trying to add an onclick event in asp.net to an item inside the dropdpwn whose url is mentioned in sitemapnode but its not happening as it is going to .aspx page.

Explantion:
I have one menu in my application underwhich we have many other submenus.
I have added one sub menu download excel and i have used sitemapnode tag to refer to this in web.sitemap page in asp.net.
I want to add direct onclick event on this sub menu so that download happen just by clicking on it without going to .aspx page.

Please help me in doing this.

Comment: Please anyone can help me out on this

Comment: Anyone please try to solve this problem, it would be of great help